# array not working properly with if else statement

Tags: javascript

I have a tic tac toe game I am working on but for some reason setting the win conditions causes the board to totally flip out and put the computer's choice on all squares left, I believe that is fine as I haven't wrote a reset for the game upon win but the problem is I believe it's causing a win when there isn't one. As always any help is much appreciated!
WARNING DO NOT RUN AS IS AS IT WILL CRASH YOUR BROWSER FROM THE PROBLEM BEING INVOLVED WITH A FOR LOOP

the specific code. The whole application is here: http://codepen.io/jeffm64/pen/BLmjvv?editors=1011

```
function checkWin() {
    for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            //checks rows
            if (board[j][0] === symbols[i] && board[j][1] === symbols[i] && board[j][2] === symbols[i]) {
                rowWin = true;
                console.log("Hey it worked");
            }
            //checks columns
            else if (board[0][j] === symbols[i] && board[1][j] === symbols[i] && board[2][j] === symbols[i]) {
                columnWin = true;
                console.log("Hey it worked");
            }
            //checks diagonals
            else if (board[j][j] === symbols[i] || board[2 - j][j] === symbols[i]) {
                diagonalWin = true;
                console.log("Hey it worked");
            } 
            else {

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I just put a `console.log("dun dun DUN!", i, j)` in that last `else` and ran the game and it seems it's never incrementing `i`. You mush have a bad condition somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the rows and columns, which is fine.
But you don't have board.length diagonals. So what you're doing there doesn't make sense.

How can you check your diagonals?
(this seems like homework so won't tell the answer)

Comment: Might have been where I had been working on it all day but definetly see the problem with the diagonals which is that it literally only checks 1 diagonal spot for a win, whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is not a win (not checked properly anyway, as mentioned by @aepure), it's the fact that computer fills in all the left fields. And it does it, because you have an infinite recursive call to `tttGame` (not in code in question). I'd suggest calling `computerAI` only if it's `player2.turn`, and turning both `player1.turn` and `player2.turn` to `false` after the game ends. This works "somehow" (removes recursive loop, so computer uses one spot at a time), but doesn't address lack of code for `"You lose"` part, nor invalid end-game check conditions. Of course, game still lacks reset, but at least it stops hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have a infinite loop, so I would suggest we get rid of that first.
Looking at the code your constantly making the computer take a turn, and that's the infinite loop bit.  The checkWin isn't working either.. But first lets get the infinite loop out the way.

This bit here ->

```
checkWin();
if(rowWin === true || columnWin === true || diagonalWin === true) {
    $(".teal").text("You win");
}
// else {  //comment out this else part, so at least play return to you.
   player1.turn = true;
   player2.turn = false;
// }
```

Comment: Ah thank you I wasn't sure what was causing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your check diagonals logic
e.g even if only one cell board[0][0]=X then diagonalWin = true

A better way to  check the win would be to check only the row,column and diagonals for the latest move